# 40 page troll patent by Magna Electronics citing 1795 sources

Tags: troll, us9014966

I found a strange patent - it is a [US 9014966 patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US9014966) called "Driver assist system for vehicle" by Magna Electronics (the biggest car part supplier in the world). The patent was applied for in 2000 and was granted in 2014, 14 years later. It has about 40 pages, very few illustrations and in my opinion "over-specifies" (lists lots of claims without proving they actually are needed for the "function"). Is this a troll patent?

Answer (score 2):

The priority date is in 2000 - it was filed in 2014. It is likely to expire in 2020. IMO it does not appear to be a "troll patent". Also the Non-patent citations are only 29.